# Replace "re.split" in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, import

```
import re
words = re.split(r'\s+', line)  
decrypted_text = []
```

What can replace this code with an easier one if not import re.

Comment: Do you want to split the string by delimeter **space** and store them into `decrypted_text` one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix would be to use the less featureful `str.split()` instead of `re.split()`:

```
line = "lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit sed"

words = line.split()

print(words)
```

Note that the '`+`' in `'\s+` is actually handled as well if you use the default argument of `str.split()`.